# Unknown revision or path not in the working tree on git reset --soft

Tags: git, git-reset, git-squash

I want to squash all the commits till a particular commit-id in a branch.
I tried using the command `git reset --soft HEAD~223`
The number 223 was generated as follows:
I ran the command `git rev-list branch-name`
and then found on which line the commit-id from which I am interested in squashing appears.
It was on line 223. So I tried running the command `git reset --soft HEAD~223`
(While on the current branch)
But I got the following error message:
`fatal: ambiguous argument HEAD~223: unknown revision or path not in the working tree`
Not sure what could be the reason for this.

Probably the way I have generated the number 223 is wrong.

Comment: Does your history contain merges? If so, the `~223` counts only the first-parent commits, but not the commits on the side branches. `git rev-list` does list all commits.

Comment: That said, since you have been able to look up the commit in the output of `git rev-list`, why, then, aren't you just using the commit ID instead of `HEAD~223`?

Comment: @j6t so just doing git `reset --soft commit-id` will it squash all the commits above it?

Comment: Unless the branch is a straight line, I don't think that's gonna be correct because `~` works on first parents _always_ and so, if there are merges, they will be counted in the lines that you saw but they would be out of the line that git will follow with `HEAD~223`. You should try with the commit id so that you do not miss it.

Comment: `git reset --soft` is not a "squash commits" command. It is more like "please reseat the branch pointer to that commit, but don't change any checked-out files nor what is recorded in the index." The squash happens only when you make a commit with the state that is still in the index at this point. "squash all the commits above it"? If your history is completely linear: yes; if it is branch-and-merge-y, not necessarily.

Comment: @j6t By non-linear history do you mean: If no branch has been merged into the current branch then the history is linear, else not.

Comment: Yes, basically that.

Comment: @j6t I ran the command `git rev-list --min-parents=2 -- count A..B` where A is the first commit and B is the last commit. The result was 0.

Answer (score 1):

Say for example, if you are in a local work tree and you have 15 commits and want to squash them, you can perform the following with `--soft`. This will set the `HEAD` at the 15th commit and then you can push your changes to your branch as if you were on the first commit, but all the subsequent changes would be included in the commit.

```bash
git reset --soft HEAD~15
git push <repository> <branch>
```

OR you can move the `HEAD` to a particular commit hash

```bash
git reset --soft <commit hash>
git push <repository> <branch>
```

OR another option is `rebase`. This will rewrite the commit hash.

It's highly recommended not to rebase if you push to a remote where others are working on the same branch.
if you want to squash PRIOR to pushing to a remote branch, you can do the following:

`<number of commits>` is the physical number of commits you want to rewrite.

`-i` is interactive mode which allows you to modify the commits

```bash
git rebase -i HEAD~15
```

OR

You can also rebase and squash any commits using the first commit hash prior to your work. This says you want to `rebase` ON TOP of the last commit before yours. When the editor opens, you need to change the keyword to `squash` on all the commits you wish to squash.

```bash
git rebase -i <hash prior to your first commit>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, generally when pointing at a commit 1 or 2 levels before your current commit, it is convenient to use `HEAD~` or `HEAD~2`. It is however never *mandatory* to use this syntax, even when your intention is to squash commits together.

---

You can use the sha of the target commit straight ahead in your `git reset` command:

```
git reset --soft <sha>
```

---

`HEAD~xx` is one of the many ways to point to a specific commit. Check [`git help gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for all the technical details -- `HEAD~xx` is explained [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADmaster3em)